# pipenv - ERROR: Couldn't install package: psycopg2

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I am running pipenv on macOS Monterey 12.4.
I have the following Pipfile:

```
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "<4.1"
pyparsing = "*"
pydot = "*"
django-extensions = "*"
coverage = "*"
djangorestframework = "~=3.13"
Markdown = "*"
django-nested-admin = "*"
drf-nested-routers = "*"
drf-access-policy = "~=1.0"
drf-yasg = "*"
drf-social-oauth2 = "*"
django-cors-headers = "*"
black = "*"
django-stubs = "*"
djangorestframework-stubs = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
sentry-sdk = "*"
django-filter = "*"
django-hashid-field = "*"
channels = "~=3.0"
djangochannelsrestframework = "*"
celery = "==5.2.2"
django-celery-results = "==2.2.0"
channels-redis = "*"
requests = "*"
django-silk = "*"
django-auto-prefetching = "*"
drf-viewset-profiler = "*"
django-lifecycle = "*"
django-notifications-rest = "*"
django-notifications-hq = "*"
django-postgrespool2 = "*"

[dev-packages]
mypy = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

This has always worked fine up to now. I tried running the command: `pipenv update sentry-sdk`, and this is the output:

```
(backend) samuelebonini@Samueles-MacBook-Pro-2 backend % pipenv update sentry-sdk
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (a39560)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a39560)...
An error occurred while installing psycopg2==2.9.4 --hash=sha256:aa184d551a767ad25df3b8d22a0a62ef2962e0e374c04f6cbd1204947f540d61 --hash=sha256:07b90a24d5056687781ddaef0ea172fd951f2f7293f6ffdd03d4f5077801f426 --hash=sha256:aafa96f2da0071d6dd0cbb7633406d99f414b40ab0f918c9d9af7df928a1accb --hash=sha256:c7fa041b4acb913f6968fce10169105af5200f296028251d817ab37847c30184 --hash=sha256:8de6a9fc5f42fa52f559e65120dcd7502394692490c98fed1221acf0819d7797 --hash=sha256:849bd868ae3369932127f0771c08d1109b254f08d48dc42493c3d1b87cb2d308 --hash=sha256:46361c054df612c3cc813fdb343733d56543fb93565cff0f8ace422e4da06acb --hash=sha256:d529926254e093a1b669f692a3aa50069bc71faf5b0ecd91686a78f62767d52f --hash=sha256:a11946bad3557ca254f17357d5a4ed63bdca45163e7a7d2bfb8e695df069cc3a --hash=sha256:839f9ea8f6098e39966d97fcb8d08548fbc57c523a1e27a1f0609addf40f777c --hash=sha256:1da77c061bdaab450581458932ae5e469cc6e36e0d62f988376e9f513f11cb5c! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 16/16 — 00:00:05
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting psycopg2==2.9.4
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached psycopg2-2.9.4.tar.gz (384 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Installing collected packages: psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Attempting uninstall: psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Found existing installation: psycopg2 2.9.3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Uninstalling psycopg2-2.9.3:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       Successfully uninstalled psycopg2-2.9.3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Rolling back uninstall of psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2-2.9.3.dist-info/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~sycopg2-2.9.3.dist-info
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/__init__.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_ipaddress.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/_ipaddress.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_json.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/_json.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_range.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/_range.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/errorcodes.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/errorcodes.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/errors.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/errors.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/extensions.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/extras.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/pool.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/pool.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/sql.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/sql.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Moving to /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/tz.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    from /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-sco0zxmv/tz.py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [55 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: error: 'Python.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <Python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                "Python.h"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<python.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <Python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                <python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       psycopg/Python.h:31:2: error: "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #error "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       psycopg/Python.h:34:10: fatal error: 'structmember.h' file not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <structmember.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       1 warning and 3 errors generated.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       required for the build and try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × Running setup.py install for psycopg2 did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [57 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         warnings.warn(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -I. -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14 -I/opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@14/server -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lz4/1.9.4/include -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: error: 'Python.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <Python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                "Python.h"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<python.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <Python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                <python.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from psycopg/adapter_asis.c:28:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       psycopg/Python.h:31:2: error: "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #error "psycopg requires Python 3.6"
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       psycopg/Python.h:34:10: fatal error: 'structmember.h' file not found
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       #include <structmember.h>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       1 warning and 3 errors generated.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       required for the build and try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   WARNING: No metadata found in /Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-tRSrcCVT/lib/python3.8/site-packages
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: legacy-install-failure
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: 
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: × Encountered error while trying to install package.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ╰─> psycopg2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: 
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: hint: See above for output from the failure.
ERROR: Couldn't install package: psycopg2
 Package installation failed...
  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/1 — 00:00:01
```

This looks like something mac-specific, but I have no idea how my environment went from working fine to having this issue. Even after this, my Pipfile.lock got correctly updated with the new version of sentry-sdk and its dependencies, but I would like to get to the bottom of this issue.

What could possibly be causing this and what's a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install libpq

```
brew install libpq
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had `psycopg2==2.9.3` before, now it's trying to install `psycopg2==2.9.4`.
Change it to `psycopg2 = "2.9.3"` in your file.

Usually you should only manually upgrade pachages' versions.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

**Other possibilities:**

- I‍f `pipenv install psycopg2` does not work properly, try `pipenv install psycopg2-binary`.
- Install `libpq` or `libpq-dev`, based on your operating system. In Ubuntu `libpq-dev` will work appropriately and for MacOS, the `libpq` is available.
- Removing the specific version from requirements.txt file would be also useful.